# How do I fix conda UnsatisfiableError of my custom conda package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, conda-build

I'm trying to package my python code to publish in on Anaconda cloud. 
The folder structure looks like this:

```
.
├── conda-recipe
│   ├── build.bat
│   ├── build.sh
│   └── meta.yaml
├── demos
│   ├── datasets
│   │   ├── com-amazon.all.dedup.cmty.txt
│   │   ├── com-amazon.ungraph.txt
│   │   ├── email-Eu-core-department-labels.txt
│   │   └── email-Eu-core.txt
│   ├── directed_example.ipynb
│   ├── email_eu_core_network_evaluation-Copy1.ipynb
│   ├── node_classification.ipynb
│   └── zacharys_karate_club_evaluation.ipynb
├── LICENSE.txt
├── README.md
├── setup.py
├── sten
│   ├── embedding.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── test
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test_system.py
├── zachary_computed.png
└── zachary_expected.png
```

The `meta.yaml` file:

```yaml
package:
  name: sten
  version: "0.1.0"

source:
  path: ..

build:
  number: 0
  noarch: generic

requirements:
  build:
    - python >=3.7
    - setuptools
  run:
    - python >=3.7
    - pypardiso >=0.2.2
    - numpy >=1.18.1
    - networkx >=2.4
    - scipy >=1.4.1
    - markdown


test:
  imports:
    - sten.embedding

about:
  home: https://github.com/monomonedula/simple-graph-embedding
  license: Apache License 2.0
  license_file: LICENSE.txt
  summary: Simple deterministic algorithm for generating graph nodes topological embeddings.
```

Command I am using to build the package (haasad is the name of the channel of the pypardiso package):
`conda build conda-recipe -c haasad`
The build is successful and I have uploaded it here:
https://anaconda.org/monomonedula/sten

However, after installation using both local build like so:
`conda install sten --use-local -c haasad`
and the build uploaded to the cloud
`conda install -c monomonedula sten -c haasad` 
I am encountering several problems.

- When using python 3.7 I am unable to import my package even though it is listed in `conda list` (I have double checked everything, I am using the correct interpreter).
- When using python 3.8 I am able to import and use it, but I am unable to install stellargraph for an unknown reason. The error message:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \ 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                                                                                                       

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions
```

Output of `conda search sten -c monomonedula --info`:

```
sten 0.1.0 py38_0
-----------------
file name   : sten-0.1.0-py38_0.tar.bz2
name        : sten
version     : 0.1.0
build       : py38_0
build number: 0
size        : 16 KB
license     : Apache License 2.0
subdir      : noarch
url         : https://conda.anaconda.org/monomonedula/noarch/sten-0.1.0-py38_0.tar.bz2
md5         : 53661562513861f9433b252c8ae7b5f4
timestamp   : 2020-05-23 19:24:36 UTC
dependencies: 
  - markdown
  - networkx >=2.4
  - numpy >=1.18.1
  - pypardiso >=0.2.2
  - python >=3.7
  - scipy >=1.4.1

sten 0.1.0 py38_0
-----------------
file name   : sten-0.1.0-py38_0.tar.bz2
name        : sten
version     : 0.1.0
build       : py38_0
build number: 0
size        : 16 KB
license     : Apache License 2.0
subdir      : noarch
url         : https://conda.anaconda.org/monomonedula/noarch/sten-0.1.0-py38_0.tar.bz2
md5         : 53661562513861f9433b252c8ae7b5f4
timestamp   : 2020-05-23 19:24:36 UTC
dependencies: 
  - markdown
  - networkx >=2.4
  - numpy >=1.18.1
  - pypardiso >=0.2.2
  - python >=3.7
  - scipy >=1.4.1
```

Output of `conda search stellargraph -c stellargraph --info`:

```
stellargraph 1.0.0 py_0
-----------------------
file name   : stellargraph-1.0.0-py_0.tar.bz2
name        : stellargraph
version     : 1.0.0
build       : py_0
build number: 0
size        : 7.8 MB
license     : Apache Software
subdir      : noarch
url         : https://conda.anaconda.org/stellargraph/noarch/stellargraph-1.0.0-py_0.tar.bz2
md5         : e62b9c897d0a5481159c1e7cb8024717
timestamp   : 2020-05-05 07:54:44 UTC
dependencies: 
  - gensim >=3.4.0
  - ipykernel
  - ipython
  - matplotlib >=2.2
  - networkx >=2.2
  - numpy >=1.14
  - pandas >=0.24
  - python >=3.6
  - scikit-learn >=0.20
  - scipy >=1.1.0
  - tensorflow >=2.1.0
```

[The repo](https://github.com/monomonedula/simple-graph-embedding/tree/refactor%26cleanup)

What am I missing here and how do I package it properly?

Comment: Are you attempting to install into an existing environment?  If so, perhaps some previously-installed package is conflicting with your new build.  What happens if you use `conda create` instead of `conda install`?

Comment: @StuartBerg I am using a clean new environment every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your `meta.yaml` file. According to an [Anaconda blog post](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/condas-new-noarch-packages):

> Noarch generic packages allow users to distribute docs, datasets, and source code in conda packages

and

> Noarch Python packages cut down on the overhead of building multiple different pure Python packages on different architectures and Python versions by sorting out platform and Python version-specific differences at install time

Because you want to distribute a pure python package, you should use `noarch: python`. Also, you don't need to set the `python` versions in `build` and `run`. I have included an updated `meta.yaml` below. It also includes the build script within it, so you no longer need the `build.sh` and `build.bat` files. It also fixes the license part to something that conda will accept (it's still Apache 2.0).

```
package:
  name: sten
  version: "0.1.0"

source:
  path: ..

build:
  number: 0
  noarch: python
  script: {{ PYTHON }} setup.py install

requirements:
  build:
    - python
    - setuptools
  run:
    - python
    - pypardiso >=0.2.2
    - numpy >=1.18.1
    - networkx >=2.4
    - scipy >=1.4.1
    - markdown

test:
  imports:
    - sten.embedding

about:
  home: https://github.com/monomonedula/simple-graph-embedding
  license: Apache-2.0
  license_family: Apache
  license_file: LICENSE.txt
  summary: Simple deterministic algorithm for generating graph nodes topological embeddings.
```

Here are the steps I used to build and install this package using the above `meta.yaml` file:

```
git clone https://github.com/monomonedula/simple-graph-embedding
cd simple-graph-embedding/
git checkout 'refactor&cleanup'
# Replace contents of `meta.yaml`
rm conda-recipe/build.sh conda-recipe/build.bat
conda create --yes -n testing python=3.7 conda-build conda-verify
conda activate testing
conda-build --channel haasad .
```

And here is what I did to install the package in the 3.7 environment. You will find the full path to the `sten-0.1.0-py_0.tar.bz2` towards the bottom of the `conda-build` log output.

```
conda install -n testing /home/jakub/miniconda3/envs/testing/conda-bld/noarch/sten-0.1.0-py_0.tar.bz2
conda activate testing
$CONDA_PREFIX/bin/python -c "import sten"
```

I also tested the installation in a python 3.8 environment.

```
conda create --yes -n testing3.8 python=3.8
conda install -n testing3.8 /home/jakub/miniconda3/envs/testing/conda-bld/noarch/sten-0.1.0-py_0.tar.bz2
conda activate testing3.8
$CONDA_PREFIX/bin/python -c "import sten"
```

`conda install --use-local sten` isn't working for me -- there is a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7024) about it.